# How to convert PDF to Gerber for PCB layout?

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication, gerber

I've got a PDF file with a PCB layout I'de like to produce - however, I need the file in Gerber format first. Is there an easy way to convert between the two? I've found this: https://swannman.wordpress.com/projects/pdf2gerb/ - does anyone have some experience with it? Does it work well? Are there better alternatives?

Comment: I haven't used that, but a quick read reveals that it requires specific drawing methods, which the author of your PDF isn't likely to have used.  Is your PDF encrypted and/or compressed, as most datasheets and appnotes are?  If so, it's not going to work.

Comment: Also, how large/complex is your design?  The PDF should use a vector drawing, which will be crisp and precise at any size.  Most EDA layout programs have some method of importing an image (for, say, a silkscreen logo).  You could blow it up to a high resolution in your PDF viewer (See [these](http://superuser.com/q/120266) [Superuser](http://superuser.com/q/38101) [questions](http://superuser.com/q/203490/) for methods) and import that to a CAD program.  That will work great for simple/small layouts, but you'll have to watch your scaling carefully!

Answer (score 3):

Its doable but is error-prone.

1) convert PDF to SVG.

For this I would recommend Inkscape as it can import PDF files and then save as SVG

2) import SVG.

KiCAD can import SVG as a graphic and then assign to a layer.

Comment: Inkscape exports to DXF too. And that's handled in most ECAD tools.

Comment: +1 but... I have found that KiCAD 6.0.11, when importing into the `User.Drawings` layer, gives the following error: `No graphics items found in file.`

Answer (score 2):

It seemed to work OK on the PDF provided in the example - the Gerbers looked OK when I imported them into GC-Prevue. However, when I created a PDF file from a PCB designed in the Pulsonix software I use, and converted it with pdf2gerb.pl, the resultant Gerber file wouldn't import into GC-Prevue.

There are some PCB manufacturers which can work from artwork supplied as Postscript files. You could convert the PDF file to Postscript by printing it to a file, using a Postscript driver.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to ask the company that did the layout for Gerbers or CAD originals.  Most companies that sell evaluation boards for their chips (e.g. TI, Altera) will do this.

Comment: hmm...never tried this!  Will have to send out a few emails...

Answer (score 2):

It's not directly possible, as a set of gerber files (including the drill file, which I count as a "gerber" even though it isn't really) contain more information than the average PDF, for example drill sizes and parameters of vias.

Comment: A PDF file can include drill holes, if they are supported in the PCB software.

Comment: @Leon Heller, I have never heard of that? The PDF file may contain polygons representing the holes (if that's what you mean), but the fabs need actual information about how the holes are drilled (like what drill size to cut, or the thickness of the plating.)

Comment: Not if the holes are drilled manually. I can get round holes in PDFs from the PCB software I use.

Comment: @Leon Heller, I suppose so, but if you were doing it manually why wouldn't you just expose the images on the PDF?

Comment: That's what I was suggesting.

Comment: You can get drill sizes, but I agree that you're unlikely to get silkscreen/soldermask/paste layers or parameters like copper thickness. Also, I'm not sure how you'd handle multiple layers - Does the PDF really draw lines that pass under other lines/polygons?

Comment: My PCB software will output a separate PDF for each layer. They can be combined, of course.

Comment: Geometry is everything, and you don't need anything else. If a PDF has holes, the conversion software will measure that geometry and produce drill commands. You can then open it in your fave PCB editor to tweak things. As for "parameters of vias" that's not anything you'll find in pdf files that are typically only used for relatively low density amateur boards. And even then, all you can have as a "parameter" is whether a via is plugged or not. That's also easy to figure out if you need to, but I doubt anyone would run into that - such designs don't go to PDF files.